# ¿Cómo mostrar solo un registro a partir de una busqueda de 3 tablas?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes 3 tablas

**Salon**

```
ID      |   Nombre_Emp        |   Lugar     |     Pre   |  Dlls   |    Finicio    |  Ffinal   

1       |   LaRuiz001         |     Y2      |     252   |  2592   |  2016-06-01   |  2016-06-10
2       |   MrsMaldonado202   |     YR3     |     692   |  2481   |  2016-06-01   |  2016-06-10
3       |   LeSalas303        |     KL4     |     125   |  2005   |  2016-05-14   |  2016-05-16
4       |   MissRojas951      |     P04     |     951   |  1899   |  2016-01-18   |  2016-03-19
```

**Evento**

```
ID_evt |   Numero   |   CodInt  |  Nombre    | 

1001   |      1     |     100    |  SANT     |   
1002   |      1     |     102    |  FNAT     |  
1003   |      1     |     103    |  HNAT     |  
1004   |      1     |     104    |  ENAT     |   
1005   |      2     |     100    |  HNAT     |  
1006   |      2     |     103    |  ENAT     |
```

**Nombre**

```
  CodNm   |   Nombre        |  

    100   |  SANTANA05X     |  
    101   |  JUANA07X       |  
    102   |  FERNANDA01X    |  
    103   |  HENA22X        |  
    104   |  ELNA85X        |
```

con el siguiente query:

```
SELECT 
        sa.ID,
        sa.Nombre_Emp,
        sa.Lugar,
        sa.Pre,
        sa.Dlls
        nm.Nombre


           FROM bdVet.Salon sa 
                   INNER JOIN bdVet.Evento ev ON sa.ID = ev.Numero
                   INNER JOIN bdVet.Nombre nm ON mm.CodNm = ev.CodInt

            WHERE   Nombre in ('SANTANA05X','FERNANDA01X','HENA22X') and
                    Dlls >=2400 AND Dlls <= 3000
                    AND Finicio >= '2016-06-01'
                    AND Ffinal <= '2016-06-30'
```

Pero el resultado aplicando el ejemplo es el siguiente:

```
ID   |   Nombre_Emp        |  Lugar     | Pre   |   Dlls    |  Nombre  
1    |     LaRuiz001       |     Y2     |  252  |  2592     |  JUANA07X
1    |     LaRuiz001       |     Y2     |  252  |  2592     |  FERNANDA01X
1    |     LaRuiz001       |     Y2     |  252  |  2592     |  HENA22X
2    |     MrsMaldonado202 |     YR3    |  252  |  2481     |  SANTANA05X
2    |     MrsMaldonado202 |     YR3    |  252  |  2481     |  FERNANDA01X
```

Como podria obtener el siguiente resultado limitado a un solo registro

***El resultado esperado es el siguiente:***

```
ID   |   Nombre_Emp        |  Lugar     |   Pre  |    Dlls     |    
1    |     LaRuiz001       |     Y2     |  252   |    2592     |  
1    |     MrsMaldonado202 |     YR3    |  692   |    2481     |
```

alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Para qué necesitas entonces hacer un join con la tabla `Nombre`?

Comment: El título de la pregunta no concuerda con el planteamiento. Título: _¿Cómo mostrar **solo un registro** a partir de una busqueda de 3 tablas?_ Planteamiento: _El resultado esperado es el siguiente:_  y muestras que quieres **dos registros** en el resultado. Me parece que puedes resolverlo con un `GROUP BY`, pero tampoco indicas por qué campos quisieras agrupar.. y si en definitiva quieres un solo registro o dos registros.

Comment: @Marcos Ah, toda la razón

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos posibles soluciones:

1. Usar el modificador [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) para agrupar los registros, por ejemplo, por el `ID` del `Salon`

   ```
   SELECT 
     sa.ID,
     sa.Nombre_Emp,
     sa.Lugar,
     sa.Pre,
     sa.Dlls

   FROM bdVet.Salon sa 
     INNER JOIN bdVet.Evento ev 
       ON sa.ID = ev.Numero
     INNER JOIN bdVet.Nombre nm 
       ON mm.CodNm = ev.CodInt

   WHERE   nm.Nombre in ('SANTANA05X','FERNANDA01X','HENA22X')
       AND sa.Dlls >=2400 
       AND sa.Dlls <= 3000
       AND sa.Finicio >= '2016-06-01'
       AND sa.Ffinal <= '2016-06-30'

   GROUP BY sa.ID
   ```
2. Usar [`DISTINCT`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) para eliminar los registros cuyos "*datos*" (`eg: todas columnas`) son iguales.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT
     sa.ID,
     sa.Nombre_Emp,
     sa.Lugar,
     sa.Pre,
     sa.Dlls

   FROM bdVet.Salon sa 
     INNER JOIN bdVet.Evento ev 
       ON sa.ID = ev.Numero
     INNER JOIN bdVet.Nombre nm 
       ON mm.CodNm = ev.CodInt

   WHERE   nm.Nombre in ('SANTANA05X','FERNANDA01X','HENA22X')
       AND sa.Dlls >=2400 
       AND sa.Dlls <= 3000
       AND sa.Finicio >= '2016-06-01'
       AND sa.Ffinal <= '2016-06-30'
   ```

   **Nota:** En este caso, si se agregara la columna `nm.Nombre`, se generaría el mismo resultado que actualmente obtienes.

Comment: Para usar el Group by no deberia usar funciones de agregado? asi como Count, SUM, etc.

Comment: @LuisFernando, el uso de dichas funciones no es algo requerido. Si no se necesita contar, sumar, etc. ¿por que habrías de agregarlas en la consulta?

Comment: Yo pensaba que siempre era requerido, muy bien tu aclaracion.